# Easy way to understand vulnerable functions while Reversing

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, patch-reversing

I have been doing reversing lately and not an experienced Reverse engineer. Mostly I do audit on binaries both fuzzing and source code.

As I am new to this stuff, I am getting some issues of understanding, in some cases I can see naked functions like memcpy,strcpy etc. but in other cases I can see only assembly functions, which is getting difficult to understand. I am trying with IDA.

I know I can use decompiler from IDA pro, but I want to go with free version and want to understand briefly.

Any resources available online, please let me know.

Comment: This type of question is [not a good fit](/help/dont-ask) for this site. Try to focus on a single, specific problem or an issue you're having.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic bullet. To understand the code you need to figure out what it's doing and this is not easy. You can start by [going line by line](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2099/60), but after some practice you should start seeing patterns at a glance.

Comment: I don't agree, if the question is about fuzzing, then it's pretty clear, that the more code - the more bugs. I.e. it's more likely to find the vulnerability in the big complex functions than in some short ones. And I think going line by line approach is something, that dies out.

Comment: @AntonKukoba: you have a point but the question was about understanding, not simply finding bugs